# Most effective method of soundproofing rackmount servers?

Tags: dell-poweredge

I'm running a 1u Dell Poweredge 1750 that is very loud even with the fans turned down. I need a good, hopefully cheap way to reduce the noise level without blocking airflow.

Comment: No, you really need a server room so you can put your server into its natural habitat :). Beside that, there exist sound-reducing 19" rack (search for "noise reducing rack").

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I plugged in both power supplies and my noise level dropped by over half.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are better off soundproofing the room the server is in, or the inside of the enclosure at any rate.

I've see some tricks with memory foam on the inside of racks to control noise pretty effectively. You want soft surfaces, but removable without mess. 1u servers are the worst though.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a bit of vinyl tape... http://www.supersoundproofingsales.com/products.asp?dept=33 something like this. Remove the lid of the server and stick a few squares on the inside of the server. If you are really ambitious you can get rubber o-rings and mount them on the stand off screws on the mainboard.

This will help. There is better stuff out there, but this will be inexpensive and easy to find.

You really are better off soundproofing the room though...

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need a sound-proofed rackmount cabinet which is purposely designed to enclose noisy equipment, such as servers, audio  and networking equipment, etc. A sound-proofed rackmount cabinet traps and absorbs unwanted noise generated inside. But I see that you have already found a cheaper way of reducing the noise level. I think that's good too.